# PayPal subscription payment failure retries

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Is it possible to increase the number of retries on failed payments for PayPal subscriptions? I can't find any global account-level setting for it.

There's a `sra` HTML button parameter, to reattempt failed recurring payments before canceling, and its documentation says that 'PayPal attempts to collect the payment **two more** times before canceling the subscription', but in-fact under an existing subscription's details it says: 'This profile will be suspended after **1 failure**', which is contradictory.

Comment: This is still a problem!  Did you figure out whether it's just a display issue, or whether setting sra to >1 will improve the # retries?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @Nick Have you got answer of this question? I am still facing same, and did not found any solution :(

Comment: No solution still. PayPal is a pain. I've moved to Stripe. You can also consider Braintree (now owned by PayPal).